# SQL - Replace value based on specific object property

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-like

I'm trying to write a conditional update statement in SQL that looks at an array of objects, and updates one object property based on another object's property. Below is an example of an object in the `signal_key` column that I'm trying to update.

```
{
  "entities": [
    {"type": "MERCHANT", "value": "AAAA"}, 
    {"type": "MERCHANT", "value": "CCC"}], 
  "signalType": "TRANSACTION", 
  "signalVersion": "0"
}
```

Based on the "value" string, I want to update the "type" from `MERCHANT` to `ID`. Is there a way for me to specifically check value instead of using something like `LIKE` that would look for a string comparison in the whole object? Below, `signal_key???` indicates the portion of the query that I am asking about.

```
UPDATE signals
SET signal_key??? =  CASE
        WHEN signal_key??? = 'AAAA' THEN 'BBBB'
        WHEN signal_key??? = 'CCC' THEN 'DDD'
        ELSE signal_key???
    END
WHERE signal_key??? IN ('AAAA', 'CCC')
```

Comment: Please see: [How to write a good SQL question?](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and add your RDBMS to your question.

Comment: Perfect, knowing that you're working with `sql-server` will help those who are familiar with it to see your question (Unfortunately, I am not), good luck!

Comment: Checking the length? Like in my answer or did you mean something else?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can update using a select/join, as well as a CTE which all seem to be needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on the length of the value string

You can use `Len(my_field)` to check the length

For example:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET some_field = CASE
        WHEN len(another_field) = 4 THEN 'BBBB'
        WHEN len(another_field) = 3 THEN 'DDD'
        ELSE 0
    END
WHERE 1=1
```

#### Edit: To update based on related data:

First create a CTE (common table expression, using `with`) that contains each item with the length of the associated items. In the example below the CTE contains each item id with the count (or "length") of associated items.

Then issue an update statement that uses the length table joined with the table you want to update.

```
with lengths (id, length) as (
    select t1.id, count(related.id)
    from test_table_1 t1
    inner join test_table_related_data related on related.parentId = t1.id
    group by t1.id
)
update t1
set t1.name = case when l.length = 1 then 'one' else 'a lot!!!' end
from test_table_1 t1
inner join lengths l on l.id = t1.id
```

Comment: sorry if my question was unclear - just made an update to remove the length part. In the example in my question I want to change the `value` based on `type`. How do I check what's at `value` when its in an array of objects?

Comment: @AKang123. You can do an update based on a select.

Comment: @AKang123. I updated my answer, let me know if you need any explanation

Answer (score 0):

To parse JSON, you should use SQL Server's JSON capabilities.

You need to use `OPENJSON` in a correlated subquery to find the right index to modify.

If you only want to modify a single value per row, you can do it like this.

```sql
UPDATE s
SET signal_key = JSON_MODIFY(
        s.signal_key,
        '$.entities[' + j.[key] + '].value',
        'BBBB')
FROM signals s
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) j.[key]
    FROM OPENJSON(s.signal_key, '$.entities') j
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.value') = 'AAAA'
) j;
```

Otherwise you need to rebuild the JSON array

```sql
UPDATE s
SET signal_key = JSON_MODIFY(
        s.signal_key,
        '$.entities',
        j.entities)
FROM signals s
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      j.type,
      value = CASE j.value
                WHEN 'AAAA' THEN 'BBBB'
                WHEN 'CCC' THEN 'DDD'
                ELSE j.value
              END
    FROM OPENJSON(s.signal_key, '$.entities')
      WITH (
        type varchar(100),
        value varchar(100)
      ) j
    FOR JSON PATH
) j(entities);
```

Comment: When I try to use the json attributes I get an error saying the data is a string. I tried to cast to a json but I'm getting an error saying string to json cast is invalid. do you know what to do in that case?

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL Server, that error doesn't sound right? Perhaps a different product such as Postgres or MySQL?